# How to remove an item from a UL once the user deselects a picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a set of pictures in a table, and when the user selects a picture it adds the id of that picture to a ul. How would I remove the item from the ul if the user deselects the picture?

here's the code I have so far

```
 $('td.n, td.p').click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('done')) {
        $(this).removeClass('done');
        $('#order').remove('#id');

    } else {

        var p = $('.picked');
        if (p.length == -1) {
            $(this).addClass('picked');

        } else {
            if ($(p[0]).text() == $(this).text()) {
                $(this).addClass('done');
                $('.picked').addClass('done')

                    var lst = $(this).attr('id');
                    var ul = $('<ul/>');
                    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                        var li = $('<li/>');
                        li.html(lst);
                        ul.append(li);
                    }
                    $('#order').append(ul);


            }

        }
    }

});
```

some of the HTML

```
 <table>
            <tr>
                <td class='n' id='a1'><img src='seat_icon.jpg'/></td>
                <td class='n' id='a2'><img src='seat_icon.jpg'/></td>
                <td class='n' id='a3'><img src='seat_icon.jpg'/></td>
                <td class='n' id='a4'><img src='seat_icon.jpg'/></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class='n' id='a6'><img src='seat_icon.jpg'/></td>
                <td class='n' id='a7'><img src='seat_icon.jpg'/></td>
                <td class='n' id='a8'><img src='seat_icon.jpg'/></td>
                <td class='n' id='a9'><img src='seat_icon.jpg'/></td>
            </tr>
 </table
```

edit:

If I add

```
 $('ul li').remove(lst);
```

It just removes the entire list. anyway I can just remove one item?

added the jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/xFvEx/1/

Comment: p.length will never == -1, so most of your code will never execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to add a [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) variable to the `ul` when it's added, then test for the existence of that `data` variable:

```
            var lst = $(this).attr('id');
            var ul = $('<ul/>').data('text', lst);

            var ulexists = $('ul').filter(function () {
                return $(this).data('text') == lst;
            });
            if (ulexists.length) {
                ulexists.remove();
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    var li = $('<li/>');
                    li.html(lst);
                    ul.append(li);
                }
                $('#order').append(ul);
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/xFvEx/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove elements from the dom (the ul) just use [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: if you want a more detailed answer please provide a jsfiddle and i'll gladly give you one

Answer (score 0):

This method should do the trick, try and tell me if it doesn't.

```
function deselect(id)
{
    $('#order').find('ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).html()==id)
    {
        $(this).remove();
    }});
}
```

Where id is the id of the related td.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in

```
$('#order').remove('#id');
```

with this you remove element with id="id" that are descendants of element with id="order" bat you didn't set any id on the li. Bat why did you complicate it so much. Try this

```
 $('td.n, td.p').click(function() {

     $(this).toggleClass('picked');

     var ids = $(".picked").map(function(){
         return $(this).attr('id');
     });

     var ul = $('<ul/>');
     for (var i = 0 ; i < ids.length  ; i++){
         ul.append($('<li/>').text(ids[i]));
     }
     $('#order').empty().append(ul);
});
```

Try it on http://jsfiddle.net/wftMz/5/